# XeTeX and xdvipdfmx problem in Texstudio

Tags: xetex

I am using MacTex2011 and the installation is standard installation, I didn't change a thing.Below is some information of my environment.

```
Sean@mac:~ > which xelatex
/usr/texbin/xelatex
Sean@mac:~ > echo $PATH 
/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/b in:/usr/texbin
Sean@mac:~ > xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (TeX Live 2011)
kpathsea version 6.0.1
Copyright 2011 SIL International and Jonathan Kew.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 4.6 [with modifications for XeTeX]
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.5; using 1.2.5
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.4.4; using 2.4.4
Using Mac OS X Carbon, Cocoa & QuickTime frameworks
```

I am using Texstudio and want to compliy a tex file. My command is:

```
"/usr/texbin/xelatex" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

what I got is the following:

```
sh: xdvipdfmx: command not found

Error: Command crashed: "/usr/texbin/xelatex" -interaction=nonstopmode "vb intro".tex
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you very much!

My preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xeCJK}  % I am Chinese, which I have to use this package to support CJK
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}       
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Helvetica}
\setsansfont{Helvetica}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont={SimHei}, ItalicFont={Adobe Kaiti Std}]{Adobe Song Std}
```

Comment: I don't have a mac. But I would 1. not use spaces in file names, 2. make tests with a small hello world document, 3. not use nonstopmode while making tests, 4. not use absolute pathes when calling commands and 5. check if `xdvipdfmx` can be found (e.g. with `xdvipdfmx --version`). Btw: you can use `xelatex --no-pdf file` to check if the first step of compilation is the problem).